# typedef declared in header file not available in source file

Tags: c++, typedef, header-files

I have a class `myclass` defined in a header file with a `typedef` in the `private:` section.

```
typedef int inttest;
```

My source file includes this header file, yet when attempting to use the typedef in the source file like so

```
inttest myclass::foo() { }
```

I get the error:

```
error: 'inttest' does not name a type
```

Why is this? Do I need to also declare the `typedef` in the source file?

Comment: Try myclass::inttest myclass::foo() {}

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all the typedef is defined in the scope of the class. So the compiler can not find the definition of the typedef if it is used as unqualified name as a return type. You could write for example

```
myclass::inttest myclass::foo() { }
```

However the compiler again will issue an error because the typedef is defined as private.

EDIT: I am sorry. The definition of the function I showed will be compiled.

However in the code that calls the function you will need to write either

```
myclass a;

int i = a.foo();
```

or

```
myclass a;

auto i = a.foo();
```

You may not write

```
myclass a;

myclass::inttest i = a.foo();
```

Comment: I believe that the return type is actually in class scope.